# How do I turn off caching in IIS7?

Tags: windows-7, web-development, cache, iis, iis-7

I'm developing an ASP classic site under Windows 7 (form a queue ladies). The problem is IIS seems to be heavily making use of its cache for both static and dynamic content which really conflicts with my 'make a small change, alt-tab, hit ctrl-F5' development style. Changes made to .asp files may take two or three refreshes to show up where as changes to .js files can take 20 times as many. How do I go about turning the caching off on my development machine?

Cheers.

in b4 stop using asp classic

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click on the server name then go to output caching.

Click Add Cache Rule then type the extensions - .aspx, .aspx.vb, .aspx.cs, .js etc. (not sure if you can do all on one)

Then simply either tick the prevent all caching or untick user-mode caching and it should stop IIS from keeping a cache of the pages.

Next time you do a full refresh, it should get the files from the hard drive and not the cache/memory

I do not currently have a machine with IIS7 on that I can muck around with so I Googled and found the picture below:

[image]

Comment: This sorted out my issue with caching the responses from a WCF service as well

Comment: You just made my day William. Thanks for that, it totally fixed my issue. Cheers!

Comment: Lot better answer given below, upvote it

Answer (score 2):

This answer helped me, (note: i'm using IIS8)
[link](http://forums.iis.net/post/1973585.aspx)

I think its better to disable "Cache" of "Output Cache feature" by clicking the "Edit Feature Settings"

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.superuser.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: @slm thanks for your advise. I'll try to add more detail later

Answer (score 1):

This blog might help: [Response caching in IIS7](http://blogs.iis.net/ksingla/archive/2006/11/16/caching-in-iis7.aspx).

It explains how this functionality can be controlled by editing system.webServer/caching section or by using IHttpCachePolicy intrinsic.